# Multiple Startup projects in Solution, in Rider

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm working on a project for a upcoming job interview. I'm used to writing C# in Visual Studio, but since I've changed to Linux, I'm trying to use Rider.

In Visual Studio you can add multiple projects as your 'Startup Project', and I'm not sure how to do this in Rider.

My file structure is:

```
BlazorApp
│   README.md
│   .gitignore    
│
└───MyApp.Web(Blazor project)
│
│___MyApp.Api(ASP.NET Core Web App with the API template)
│   
└───MyApp.Models(Class library)
```

Where `MyApp.Api` should start first and afterwards `MyApp.Web`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

1. In the run config drop down, select "Edit Configuration..."
2. At the top of the left hand menu, click "+"
3. Find and select "Compound"
4. Name it
5. Use the "+" button to add the projects you'd like to start together
6. Select that configuration when you run it

---

Edit the confuration: 
[image]

Find and select the Compound configuration: 
[image]

Add the projects: 
[image]

Select it when you run it: 
[image]

##### Note

---

The compound configuration is just a grouping of existing run configurations so if you need to set environment variables or program or runtime arguments, you can:

1. In the run config drop down, select "Edit Configuration..."
2. Click on the run configuration you need to update from the left hand menu
3. Make the desired updates on the right hand side
4. Save the changes.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to set runtime arguments? I am not seeing a way to do that (I want to run the same project with different arguments)

Comment: @JoePhillips, see if the latest update at the bottom helps any.

Comment: How do you setup this to run only one of those projects in debug mode? Alternatively how can you tell the debugger to stop on breakpoint of a specific project and ignore the same breakpoint in other projects?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984, I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking how to run multiple instances of the same project?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes. I figured it out, I just made two different configurations for the same project with different command arguments and put them both in compound. And it works exactly how I want.

Answer (score 0):

In Rider 2023.3, they have added `Multi-Launch configuration﻿`, which allows you to start two or more projects in an order that you specify yourself. With the previous `Compound configuration`, you were not able to specify the launch order of the projects. So if this is something you need, check it out. You can read about how to set it up on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/2023.3/Run_Debug_Multiple.html#multi_launch.

Here's a GIF from the documentation, which shows how to run multiple projects using the Multi-Launch configuration:

[image: Gif image showing how to set up multi project launch in Rider]

And here's a copy of the text that explains the steps:

[image: Documentation of how to run multiple projects]